# How to rename a PostgreSQL cluster?

Tags: postgresql, maintenance

I googled and found [this old web page](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/rename-a-cluster-td2083895.html), which said just to change the name of the directory.  I tried it but it didn't work:

```
$ pg_lsclusters 
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
8.4     main      5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main       /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log
9.1     main      50420 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main       /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log$ pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main stop

$ pwd
/var/lib/postgresql/9.1

$ ls
main

$ mv main oldmain

$ pg_ctlcluster 9.1 oldmain start
Error: specified cluster does not exist
```

PostgreSQL 9.1.4, Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I'm confused. A PostgreSQL cluster does not have a name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I added pg_lsclusters output above. I'm new to this, but I believe you can have multiple clusters, and you have to identify which cluster you are talking to by its name (or maybe directory name, I'm not sure).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Cluster names are specific to multi-version/multi-cluster architecture in Debian, Ubuntu & friends. I hope my answer can shed some light on this.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks I didn't know that. You live and learn ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: version 166 of the `postgresl-common` package added `pg_renamecluster`. See [Ilya's new answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176612/3684) about that.

---

**In older versions** (including Postgres 9.1.4 on Ubuntu 11.10) the name of a cluster is bound to the name of the data directory in the "Multi-Version/Multi-Cluster PostgreSQL architecture" introduced by Martin Pitt. This is shipped with Debian packages (Debian, Ubuntu and related distributions). For a detailed description of the architecture, see:

```
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz
```

[Or browse the file online here.](https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common/blob/master/README.md)

Other installations do not have all of these features, so some people may be confused when you talk about cluster names.

Just renaming the data directory does not work, because you have to change the directory in`/etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>` accordingly.

And there are a couple of settings in your `postgresql.conf`, that have to be adjusted, too. Run a grep in the directory to see:

```
postgres@db:/etc/postgresql/9.1/main$ grep 'main' ./*
```

Comment: Thanks @Erwin_Brandstetter!  Nice detailed answer with useful link to Martin Pitt's architecture.  I will give your answer a try.

Comment: The link to https://people.debian.org/~mpitt/architecture.html no longer works

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks, I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Debian/Ubuntu has a `pg_renamecluster` command (available in "postgresql-common" package) which does just what you need:

- renames config and data directory,
- renames existing log files,
- changes a number of settings in the `postgresql.conf`.

[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/pg_renamecluster.1.html).

Note for Systemd users: generators are used to create unit file (i.e. service) for each PostgreSQL cluster. So after the `pg_renamecluster` you should reload Systemd config, enable and start new service:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable postgresql@<version>-<new cluster name>.service
sudo systemctl start postgresql`

Comment: It should be mentioned that  [`pg_renamecluster` was only added to the unstable release with postgresql-common (166) in Feb 2015](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/p/postgresql-common/unstable_changelog). IOW: not available in Debian before jessie-backports. That's years after the question was asked and hardly applicable to Postgres 9.1 (though you *can* run an outdated pg 9.1 cluster in the updated infrastructure).